# Is there a way to get keyframe animations to work with webkit text clipping?

Tags: css

I've been trying to do a simple keyframe animation with text fading in and moving up. It works, however on webkit clipped text, the text will not render. Css is below.

```
  .animationA{
    margin-top: 10%;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: textscroll 500ms ease-in 250ms 1 forwards;
  }


    @keyframes textscroll {
    0%{
      margin-top: 10%;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      margin-top : 15px;
      opacity: 1;
    }

  }

  .hero .hero-content h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: rgb(0,212,255);
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(0,212,255,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 77%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 100%);  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

If I attempt to have the h1 element animate, it simply does not appear. Any help on this solve would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with a span nested in the H1 which was breaking the keyframe animation for some reason. I didn't even think to include the HTML, which is my bad.